# Why would app crash if delegate uses assign instead of weak?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

I have seen [report](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/892) that if a delegate uses assign instead of weak, the app crashes.  Why?

Example: [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/892)

Comment: Because if the object is deallocated, `assign` will still have pointer to the previously deallocated object (a "dangling pointer") whereas if you used `weak` the pointer will be set to `nil` when the object is deallocated.

Answer (score 3):

With ARC a `weak` ivar will be automatically set to `nil` when the ivar object is deallocated.  That means that if your delegate is destroyed and you try to message the delegate you'll just message nil, which has no effect.  If the delegate ivar was merely `assign` then you would message some chunk of memory that no longer contained a valid object.

Answer (score -1):

The only difference between `assign` and `weak` is that weak does extra work to avoid some common crashing bugs. The drawback, however, is that `assign` has much better performance than `weak`.

Specifically, when an object is released, any `weak` property pointing to it will be set to `nil`. Any `assign` property pointing to it will be left pointing at the object that is no-longer used.

And some other object is likely to be placed at the same location in memory as the old object, so suddenly instead of an instance of `MyDelegate` you might have a `UIImage` object in the same location in memory, or perhaps a float value, or anything at all.

So you should always use `weak`, for everything. But if you run into performance problems, check if `weak` is the cause, and consider switching to `assign` after learning how to avoid those crashing bugs.

For a delegate you should pretty much always use `weak`. Normally you'd only pick `assign` if you are dealing with millions of objects. Typically that doesn't happen with delegates.